# what is the best way to migrate data from one sharepoint online library to another sharepoint online library within the same site collection. Any tool

Tags: migration, document, library, data

what is the best way to migrate data from one sharepoint online library to another sharepoint online library within the same site collection. Any third party tool to recommend?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Move to**

If you're just moving one set of files, try the "Move to" option in the library user interface.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-or-copy-files-in-sharepoint-00e2f483-4df3-46be-a861-1f5f0c1a87bc

**Option 2: OneDrive Sync**

Another alternative would be to use the library sync option for both libraries and then use Windows File Explorer to copy/paste the files.

**Option 3: PowerShell**

A third option would be to use PowerShell if this is something you need to script. A sample script for SharePoint Online document libraries is at the bottom of the following web page:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-copy-file-between-document-libraries-using-powershell.html

Here is info on getting started with the PnP PowerShell module you will need to run the script:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

**Option 4: Paid Utility**

If you have funds and want a utility with a user interface, ShareGate is an example of the paid utilities available. They have a free trial available to test with, but the full version runs over $4,00 per year.

https://support-desktop.sharegate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000640388-Walkthrough-Copy-Content

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Since I need to transfer big amount of data, what tool could you recommend?

Comment: If the user interface "Move to" option isn't efficient enough or there's too much data for your situation, then the free tool I would use is PowerShell. If you have funds, then there are a number of utilities available.